# Do the scriptures support adapting to different times?

Tags: scripture

The scriptures were made a very long time ago. Did the creators vouch for the compatibility of their views and ideologies for all of the future generations? Or is there any mention to adapt oneself with changing times in the sense that they encouraged  modifications to ideologies with changing times?

Comment: Yes, rules change in every Yuga.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the rules that govern and duties to be followed by mankind depend on and differ according to the ages. See the following verses from the Manu Smriti:

> 1.84. The life of mortals, mentioned in the Veda, the desired results of sacrificial rites and the (supernatural) power of embodied
>   (spirits) are fruits proportioned among men according to (the
>   character of) the age.
>
> 1.85. **One set of duties (is prescribed) for men in the Krita age, different ones in the Treta and in the Dvapara, and (again) another
>   (set) in the Kali,** in a proportion as (those) ages decrease in length.
>
> 1.86. In the Krita age the chief (virtue) is declared to be (the performance of) austerities, in the Treta (divine) knowledge, in the
>   Dvapara (the performance of) sacrifices, in the Kali liberality alone.

So, for example, performing austerities, like they used to be performed in ancient times, are not suitable for people living in Kali Yuga. They need to adapt accordingly as prescribed.

Adapting according to situations is also allowed. For example, rules which are there for normal situations are made less strict when life is in distress.

So, there are 1. Normal Dharmas and 2. Apad Dharmas (which are less strict).

> Manu smriti 1.116. (The law concerning) the behaviour of Vaisyas and
>   Sudras, the origin of the mixed castes, the law for all castes in
>   times of distress and the law of penances,
>
> Manu Smriti 4.2. A Brahmana must seek a means of subsistence which
>   either causes no, or at least little pain (to others), and live (by
>   that) **except in times of distress**.